# Incorrect plotting of point and line

Tags: python, shapely, matplotlib

I'm learning how I can plot shapely's geometries with matplotlib. I have the point and line below:

```
point = Point(-170.212027219433033, 80.62335710279816)
linestring = LineString([(-0.446866298572111, -1.1810037890834053), (-36.57919844025919, 19.94938832911169)])
```

With code below I try to plot point and line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xlabel('X coordinate', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y coordinate', fontsize=15)

plt.plot(point, label='Point')
plt.plot(linestring, label='LineString')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

But the result is unexpected:
[image]

I don't understand why I don't see the point and linestring correctly. What I've done wrong?

On QGIS I see this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib only knows x,y coordinates:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xlabel('X coordinate', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y coordinate', fontsize=15)
ax.plot(*point.xy, 'ro', label='Point')
ax.plot(*linestring.xy, label='LineString')
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]

Comment: What mean `ro`?

Comment: "r"= red, "o"=marker (red marker),  Otherwise  use `ax.scatter(*point.xy, c='r')`